# Membership days count is different for web and app

Tags: bug, ios-app

For any new user membership days count is different in web and iOS app. E.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/345567/adalcar):

> [image: ios]

> [image: web]

One day is lost in the app.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Also, profile views have diff values.